# Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices at (−1,1), (−5,5), (−2,−1), and (−6,3).

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices at (−1,1), (−5,5), (−2,−1), and (−6,3).

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..

I let:

$a = |DC| = (-2,-1) - (-6,3) = (4,-4)$

$b = |AD| = (-1,1) - (-5,5) = (4,-4)$

so:

$\begin{bmatrix} 4&-4\\4&-4\end{bmatrix} \implies $ Area $= -16 + 16 = 0$ ?

The determinant is the area of the parallelogram is it not?

Comment: Not sure how you're labelling vertices, but $a$ appears to be $|CD|$, while $b$ appears to be $|AB|$. You get a result of zero because those lines are parallel.

Comment: You are correct that was the problem. The answer is $|-12|$